# Cross database query takes abnormaly long to run despite using indices as shown by EXPLAIN

Tags: mysql, sql, database-performance, explain, indices

```
Table_A
id int(11)
sku varchar(24)
Total number of records 250000, sku indexed

Table_B
id int(11)
sku varchar(16)

Total number of records - 180000, sku indexed
```

The following query has been running for over 30 minutes

```
Select count(*) 
from Table_A 
where not exists(select 1 from Table_B where Table_B.sku = Table_A.sku)
```

while 
Select count(*) from Table_B where exists(select 1 from Table_A where Table_A.sku = Table_B.sku) is executed in less than a second.

Could somebody explain what could be happening?

Forgot to mention Table_A and Table_B are in different databases

```
mysql> describe db1.table_a;
+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field      | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| prodcut_id | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| sku        | varchar(24) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)



mysql> describe db2.table_b;
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| sno   | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| sku   | varchar(24) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)




mysql> explain select count(*) from db2.table_b where not exists(select 1 from db1.table_a where table_a.sku = table_b.sku);
+----+--------------------+---------+-------+---------------+------+---------+------+--------+--------------------------+
| id | select_type        | table   | type  | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows   | Extra                    |
+----+--------------------+---------+-------+---------------+------+---------+------+--------+--------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY            | table_b | index | NULL          | sku  | 27      | NULL | 181286 | Using where; Using index |
|  2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | table_a | ref   | sku           | sku  | 75      | func |      1 | Using where; Using index |
+----+--------------------+---------+-------+---------------+------+---------+------+--------+--------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)


mysql> explain select count(*) from db1.table_a where not exists(select 1 from db2.table_b where table_b.sku = table_a.sku);
+----+--------------------+---------+-------+---------------+------+---------+------+--------+--------------------------+
| id | select_type        | table   | type  | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows   | Extra                    |
+----+--------------------+---------+-------+---------------+------+---------+------+--------+--------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY            | table_a | index | NULL          | sku  | 75      | NULL | 277030 | Using where; Using index |
|  2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | table_b | index | NULL          | sku  | 27      | NULL | 181286 | Using where; Using index |
+----+--------------------+---------+-------+---------------+------+---------+------+--------+--------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Try EXPLAIN that query

Comment: I did and I get the following 
id | select_type        | table | type  | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows   | Extra                    |
+----+--------------------+-------+-------+---------------+------+---------+------+--------+--------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY            | p     | index | NULL          | sku  | 194     | NULL | 277030 | Using where; Using index |
|  2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | md    | index | NULL          | sku  | 27      | NULL | 181286 | Using where; Using index

Comment: DEPENDENT SUBQUERY isn't very good, try JOIN solution as @Notulysses sugesst

Comment: maybee problem should be, that you have `sku` in first table declared as `varchar(24)` and in second as `varchar(16)`

Comment: This is most likely going to result in a O(m*n) query. A `JOIN` should be your preferred way of doing this anyway.

Comment: It isn't m*n query, because subquery checks only index for checking exsistence of record (as EXPLAIN says `Using index`)

Comment: @Unlink then how would you account for the 30'+ of running time?

Comment: surprisingly querying the other way, SELECT COUNT(*) FROM DB2.TABLE_B B WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM DB1.TABLE_A A WHERE A.sku = B.sku) executes in less than a second.

Comment: @okiharaherbst i really don't know, it shouldn't be so slowly
**a5995** try edit your post and give there formated version of explaing, something is wrong...

Comment: @a5995: I have no access to MySQL right so I cannot test it myself but I'm seeing that you have `sku varchar(24)` and `sku varchar(16)`. Could you try increasing the 16 to 24 or reducing the 24 to 16?

Comment: Can you put up the full query and table declares. Your EXPLAIN shows the key length on the main table as being 193 bytes - about 6 times the max length of a row on that table. Problem could be the details.

Comment: I second @Kickstart's suggestion. There's more to your problem that is not said here as I just ran test with similar queries on 300K samples and the query times are around 2 sec.

Comment: @ okiharaherbst changed sku to varchar(24)

Comment: it's strange behavior, why mysql execute that query this way...
maybee something with keys, i really don't know, why have different lenght. **Try dopping and creating indexes agin**

Comment: Thanks guys for your replies. The problem was with the collation, they were different. Changed the collation and the query completed in about 2 secs.

Comment: @a5995 Thanks for sharing your findings that seem a very likely explanation if MySQL has to convert encodings/collations in the `JOIN` conditions. This would moreover explain a similar behavior I experienced myself with an imported MySQL dump. I ended up reimporting the data differently and the problem was solved so I didn't care any longer but the underlying reasons were probably the same. Actually, I strongly think that you should post this as an answer to your own question and accept it as it will definitely  help others who do cross-database queries in the future.

Comment: @a5995 That being said, this still doesn't explain why your second _query executes in less than a second_...

Answer (score 2):

In MySQL `LEFT JOIN` should have a better performance than `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT COUNT(a.*) 
FROM Table_A a LEFT JOIN Table_B b ON a.sku = b.sku
WHERE b.sku IS NULL
```

Comment: Tried this as well, but even this query runs for over half an hour. Puzzled as to what could be causing this delay.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested posting this as the answer.
Found that the problem was with the collation. Changed the collation of the tables to be identical and the query completed in about 2 secs.